# Executors.newFixedThreadPool() returning null on Constructor instanced by @Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

On my application I want centralize the control of threads, control the submit() tasks, count, activeCount and others informations about the thread pool. The tasks are submited all the time by many services on the application, so to see the metrics I want create a Scheduled job to print those informations periodically. Problem is returning null at the initialize application when create Executors.newFixedThreadPool().

Controll class

```
public class ThreadPoolWorkControl {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThreadPoolWorkControl.class);

    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

    public ThreadPoolWorkControl() {
        this.executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); // NULL HERE (Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null)
    }

    public int submitTask(Runnable task) {
        executor.submit(task);
        return executor.getQueue().size();
    }

    public ThreadPoolExecutor getExecutor() {
       return this.executor;
    }

}
```

Configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ThreadPoolWorkControlConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolWorkControl threadPoolWorkControl() {
        return new ThreadPoolWorkControl();
    }

}
```

Job

```
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class InfoThreadsJob {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InfoThreadsJob.class);

    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolWorkControl threadPoolWorkControl;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
    public void infosThreadPool() {
        LOGGER.info("M=infosThreadPool, Msg=Active Size: {}, Pool Size: {}, Queue size: {}", threadPoolWorkControl.getExecutor().getActiveCount(), threadPoolWorkControl.getExecutor().getPoolSize(), threadPoolWorkControl.getExecutor().getQueue().size());

    }

}
```

Errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadPoolWorkControl' defined in class path resource [.../configuration/ThreadPoolWorkControlConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [.../ThreadPoolWorkControl]: Factory method 'threadPoolWorkControl' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Show full stacktrace.

Comment: I tried your setup in a sample project. It is working as expected without error. Just incase, my `ThreadPoolExecutor` is from `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` as there are few. May be something else you have in your config?

Comment: I'm using this lib too.